# NEO4J - Optional query very slow

Tags: performance, neo4j, graphql, match, option-type

I'm new with Neo4J and i have the following query, how i can make it faster? It really takes a long time

```
MATCH (vintage:Vintage)-[:MADE_FROM]->(wine:Wine)
OPTIONAL MATCH (vintage)-[:DESIGNATED_BY]->(app:Appellation)
OPTIONAL MATCH (vintage)-[:RANKED]->(ranking:Ranking)
OPTIONAL MATCH (vintage)-[:HAS_NOTE]->(note:Note)<-[:REVIEWS]-(reviewer:Reviewer)
WITH reviewer, note, app, wine, vintage ORDER BY vintage.code ASC, vintage.year DESC
RETURN { vintages: collect({ uid: vintage.uid, year: vintage.year,  
      cv: vintage.referencePrice})[10 * (1 - 1)..10 * 1], total: size(collect(vintage)) } as vintage
```

[Explain model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMaC2.png)

Comment: You are doing a database scan without any starting node so it is expected to be slow.

Comment: Please supply the PROFILE plan, that will show row information between the operations. Also please expand all elements of the plan.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little strange that you're getting all this optional info (app, ranking, note, reviewer) but you're not doing anything with it. You're not returning any of that, you're only returning information from the vintage.

If you're not going to use it, don't match to it.

But if your intent is to make sure at least one of such paths exist per pattern, use a WHERE clause for these, that will also avoid cross product issues if multiple paths exist for some of the OPTIONAL MATCHes.

But since you're using OPTIONAL MATCHes, it seems like you don't want their presence in the graph or absence to control whether or not the vintage is returned. As such, they aren't serving any purpose, and are only making your query slower. The only hard requirement you seem to have is that the :Vintage is made from :Wine (though if all :Vintages are made from :Wine, you can remove that part too). We'll keep that and remove the others.

Also your calculation for the total vintages isn't correct. Since you are using OPTIONAL MATCHes, you don't care about a vintage meeting the patterns there, so we can just total the vintages before MATCHING to the individual nodes.

Lastly it wasn't clear that you're only looking for a subset of nodes, so we can do away with the list slice approach and use SKIP and LIMIT instead. This is also probably why your query is taking so long...it's calculating all vintage information, but you're only taking a slice of it at the end, so you're doing a lot of work that is only thrown away at the end.

Try this instead:

```
MATCH (vintage:Vintage)
WHERE (vintage)-[:MADE_FROM]->(:Wine)
WITH count(vintage) as total

MATCH (vintage:Vintage)
WHERE (vintage)-[:MADE_FROM]->(:Wine)
WITH total, vintage
ORDER BY vintage.code ASC, vintage.year DESC
SKIP 0
LIMIT 10
WITH total, collect({ uid: vintage.uid, year: vintage.year, cv: vintage.referencePrice}) as vintages
RETURN { vintages:vintages, total:total} as vintage
```

If there was a purpose to those OPTIONAL MATCHes, please explain in comments, and I'll see how the query can be modified to handle them.